# How to fetch Swagger definition from a password-protected remote server in Maven

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

Rather than copy a Swagger definition from another project, I want to fetch the current version direct from Gitlab. I thought that I might be able to link to the `server` settings in `settings.xml` but that doesn't seem to work.

How do I pass the server credentials to Maven in order to access the yaml? Or is this not the right way to do it?

```
<execution>
    <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
    </goals>
    <id>generate-swagger-attrstore</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <server>gitlab</server>
        <mainClass>io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen</mainClass>
        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
        <arguments>
            <argument>generate</argument>
            <argument>-l</argument>
            <argument>java</argument>
            <argument>-c</argument>
            <argument>${swagger.dir}/attrstore-codegen-config.json</argument>
            <argument>-i</argument>
            <argument>${swagger.attrstore}</argument>
            <argument>-o</argument>
            <argument>${basedir}</argument>
            <argument>--library</argument>
            <argument>okhttp-gson</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```